# How to deal with zipcode as a confounding variable in the logistic regression model in SAS?

Tags: sas

Zipcode is a character variable in the USRDS database, but in my logistic regression model, it plays as a covariate on the right of the model equation. Does it need dummy coding or need to transfer to numerical variable? If needs to be transfer to numeric variable, what's the coding?

I'm hoping to have an answer regarding dummy on zipcode as it has so many values and if zipcode as a character variable needs to be transferred to numeric variable, I expect to have the exact coding.

Comment: That might depend on the country that your data comes from. But in most cases there is a system how the zip code is built up. In the US, e.g., the first three digits represent a region so that you might find correlations if the numbers are similar or adjacent. To transform a character variable to a numerical you can use the SAS function "input".

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Moreover, I want to classify all the county code into four region of the U.S.: Northeast, Mid-west, West and South and then I can describe the number of patient population of each region. Could you kindly provide code regarding this transfer?

Answer (score 0):

Taking your comment into account you need one or two new columns that are created like:

```
substr(zip_code,1,1) as zone, 
substr(zip_code,1,3) as region   [SQL code]
```

or

```
zone=substr(zip_code,1,1); 
region=substr(zip_code,1,3);        [SAS code]
```

Then you have to decide on how you bundle the zones or regions into your desired groups: NorthEast could be zones 0 and 1, West could be zones 9 and 8 and so on. But if, e.g., you want to put Delaware into the south then you need to use the new column 'region' because New York and Delaware are both in zone 1.